# Removing description home page product box

Tags: opencart-3

[image]

How to remove the description on homepage product box? I tried many ways, but it's not workable.

Answer (score 0):

The home page is probably just using the category template (find out in the layouts what is actually shown on your home page).

To remove the description from category pages (all category pages), comment-out or remove line 135:

{{ product.description }}

in catalog/view/theme/default/template/product/category.twig

Then you probably need to change your css to make the product boxes smaller...

Comment: You told me like I followed them and removed them. But no change

Comment: Do you have another theme installed? This only removes it from the default theme. Also, clear your cache after making the change.